# What is the average number of articles written per author in a year and has it increased recently?

Tags: journals, citations, productivity, bibliometrics

Did anyone research the data about scientific productivity? I.e. what is the average number of articles written by author in a year in a specific field? I am  referring to average, since this is maybe easiest to calculate, but it would be interesting to see the distribution data too. This of course depends on how many journals we want to scope, but I would be interested to see any data on say most popular fields like physics, mathematics, chemistry, biology, psychology, economics, etc (order is of no importance).

Comment: can you rephrase/edit your question to define why one would want to study such numbers? in other words, give us a context of the question

Comment: It's been my impression that quantity is not as critical as quality.  A paper in a reputable journal is worth more than several papers in their less reputable counterparts.

Comment: A single number "papers per author per year" is nearly meaningless.  Publication and coauthorship rates vary radically from one field to another — in many subfields of physics, people publish tons of papers with lots of coauthors; in many subfields of economics, people publish few papers, with few or no coauthors.

Comment: I need to settle argument with a colleague. I know that quantity is not quality.

Comment: @JeffE, yes different fields have varying number per articles written. So this is why in my question I mentioned that I want to see the data for different fields.

Comment: @Paul do you have data to back that up? My recollection of Byrnes's study in psychology (http://pss.sagepub.com/content/18/4/283.short) is that that is not the case for tenure review in the US.

Comment: @ElCid I think knowing these numbers for your field can be valuable to both new people in the field and the tenure review process for calibration purposes.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: Paul's contention is certainly consistent with my experience in computer science, on both sides of hiring, promotion, and tenure decisions.  (We tend to refer to "Publications in less reputable counterparts" as "non-publications".)

Comment: Number of articles *written*? Or number of articles in which someone shows up as one of many authors? Because those are two very different things.

Answer (score 7):

A comprehensive review was conducted in the field of [psychology](http://pss.sagepub.com/content/18/4/283.short) in relation to publication rates and tenure. There is also a "fun" review related to beer consumption and publication in the field of [avian evolutionary biology](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0030-1299.2008.16551.x/full).

---

doi: 10.1111/j.1467-9280.2007.01889.x
Psychological Science April 2007 vol. 18 no. 4 283-286

Comment: From the psychology study: _It is possible that the only way to fully understand this finding will be to conduct detailed case studies in which chairpersons or colleagues of the candidates for tenure are interviewed about the cases._ — Really?  Ya think?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson the link works for me. Added the doi at the end.

Comment: Thanks; it works for me now too.  Maybe just a server hiccup.

Answer (score 3):

Though this is not a direct answer to your query, this hopes to lead to more productive / useful answers.

See this [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index), on Hirsch index or h-index that is a widely accepted measure of

> both the productivity and impact of the published work of a scientist
>   or scholar.

The article also points to other indices on scientific/academic productivity and impact in the field.

The [SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System Abstract Service](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/ads_abstracts.html) provides a gateway to the online Astronomy and Physics literature. A new interface of the ADS provides a tool to visualize the author and paper networks; that tells you how productive the author is, quantified with the number of collaborators and papers produced.

For e.g. see this [link](http://labs.adsabs.harvard.edu/ui/cgi-bin/topicSearch?q=Narlikar&qtype=NEW&db_key=AST&db_key=PRE&arxiv_sel=astro-ph&arxiv_sel=gr-qc); a search for the name **Narlikar**. On top of the resulting page, next to *Top 200 results*, you can see a drop-down menu, on which you can select various options like Author Network, Paper Network etc to get various  visualizations.

You can contact the project personnels here http://adsabs.harvard.edu/ . They do conduct studies on bibliographic data, which is one of the measure of academic productivity.

---

Update :

Here is a link to the articles that cite [J. E. Hirsch](http://www.pnas.org/content/102/46/16569.full)'s article - *An index to quantify an individual's scientific research output*- on h-index via Google Scholar http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=link:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pnas.org%2Fcontent%2F102%2F46%2F16569.abstract

Comment: Widely _used_ perhaps, but widely _accepted_?  Really?

Comment: There is a scope for another question, then :-)

Comment: I have added a question http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/which-is-the-most-accepted-measure-for-an-individuals-academic-productivity

Answer (score 2):

In the subject that I am familiar with, political science, there is a recent study using bibliometric data on patterns of publishing in journals - maybe this could be interesting (and might be similar to already mentioned work in other comments): https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/ps-political-science-and-politics/article/patterns-of-publishing-in-political-science-journals-an-overview-of-our-profession-using-bibliographic-data-and-a-coauthorship-network/D946105595ED2C314AE2A04138F7A5B6

As the authors state:

> We drew on more than 67,000 papers published from 1990 to 2013 in one
>   of today’s 96 core journals. The network consists of more than 40,000
>   authors located worldwide.

and regarding your question, they find this:

> Whereas some are highly productive in terms of publications, the
>   majority of authors published only a single paper, which suggests
>   significant turnover in the community.

You should have a closer look at it (although polsci is not in your list of mentioned disciplines)

Answer (score 1):

Papers on coauthorship networks such as [Newman (2004)](http://www.pnas.org/content/101/suppl_1/5200.full) have the descriptive statistics on publication rates in different fields, e.g. publications per person per year.